Snap Store Security Policy or Ubuntu App center software is secure
Please tell me ,
Snap Store Whats up application is secure ?
and any software is secure?
Any people from make other software is secure?
Any ubuntu app center software is secure?

"and any software is secure? Any people from make other software is secure?" No one can answer this.

Are you asking about security or privacy? The tag you use makes me wondering.

This question is similar to: How to determine if an application is safe for use on Ubuntu. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Most of the applications in the snap store are made and distributed by third party developers.
All software in the official repositories are maintained by Ubuntu and Debian developers, and are written by third party developers.
No one can answer whether a software is secure or not. It is upto you to decide whether you would trust the developer.
Majority of the popular free software are cross-checked by other developers.
No one can even determine whether non-free software (like Microsoft Windows, the Official WhatsApp client (not even considering the unofficial client in snap store)) are secure. Many non-free software (e.g. Windows or WhatsApp) are known to contain backdoors. See this and this.
